# How to delete a specifil line by line number in a file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a simple Phyton script that alway delete the line number 5 in a tex file, and replace with another string always at line 5. I look around but I could't fine a solution, can anyone tell me the correct way to do that? Here what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import od
import sys
import fileimput

f= open('prova.js', 'r')
filedata = f,read()
f.close ()

newdata = "mynewstring"

f = open('prova.js', 'w')
f.write(newdata, 5)
f.close
```

basically I need to add newdata at line 5.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please post the code you have tried and show what is not working right.

Comment: @MarkyPython the problem is that I didn't write nothing because I don't know ho to start to do that..can you please point me to the right function? I just need to delete line number 5 from a text file... I know how to open read and write to file, and I know ho to delete a string what I do't know is how to delete a specific line..

Comment: If you know how to open a file and read it line by line that is a start... Try at least putting that in your question

Comment: Your reasons for asking do not make the question better suited for this site.  How it is currently written, your question is asking someone to give you some code.  That is not what StackOverflow is for.  We are here to help you with *specific* problems you have with code you currently have.

Comment: @M.T yes...but how can I write something to line 5? I can't find any reference to do that!

Comment: `Read line, count line, if count != 5: write line else: write other line. Repeat`

Comment: I edited my question to include the code I have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible simple solution to remove/replace 5th line of file. This solution should be fine as long as the file is not too large:

```
fn = 'prova.js'
newdata = "mynewstring"
with open(fn, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
    #to delete line use "del lines[4]"
    #to replace line:
    lines[4] = newdata
with open(fn,'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Comment: thanks very much! But actually I need to delete line 5 and replace the same line with the string in the newdata variable..

Comment: @FabioEnne then instead of `del lines[4]` you would do `lines[4]=newdata`

Comment: yep! It works! the only problem is that it keeps on adding blank rows after every line..

Comment: @FabioEnne fixed it. I have been avoiding using `readlines` so much I forgot it included the newline.

Answer (score -1):

I will try to point you in the right direction without giving you the answer directly.  As you said in your comment you know how to open a file. So after you open a file you might want to split the data by the newlines (hint: `.split("\n")`). Now you have a list of each line from the file. Now you can use list methods to change the 5th item in the list (hint: change the item at `list[4]`).  Then you can convert the list into a string and put the newlines back (hint: `"\n".join(list)`). Then write that string to the file which you know how to do. Now, see if you can write the code yourself. Have fun!